# Building Blender on Fedora 20, OSL compilation failed

Tags: c++, fedora, blender

When trying to build Blender on Fedora 20, I got the following error when running the **install_deps.sh** script:

```
Linking CXX shared library liboslexec.so
[ 81%] Built target oslexec
make: *** [all] Error 2
ERROR! OpenShadingLanguage-1.5.11 failed to compile, exiting
```

Does anyone know how to fix this compilation error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need more information. The `install_deps.sh` script will download and compile each library for you, you should be able to find the OSL source files, and manually try building it.

As it is a linking error chances are a library (or required version) is missing, or not where it is expected to be found.

From the OSL build directory you can run ccmake and under advanced options you will find `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` that when enabled will add more detail to the output.

After a quick look at the script, you should find a folder called `$HOME/src/blender-deps/OpenShadingLanguage-1.5.11/build` where you can run `ccmake ../` or you can run `cmake-gui` if you have it installed and point it at that folder, and then run `make`.

Comment: thank you for your help. It was only a matter of manually compiling OSL. The only command I had to insert for the make to be successful was:  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib` so that the compiler finds  `libopencv_core.so.3.0.0`.